# Python not importing Leap Motion library

Tags: python, leap-motion

I am trying to get the basics of Leap Motion running in python.

```
import os, sys, inspect, thread, time
```

Code can be seen here.. 
http://pastie.org/10883595

I get an error ....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sample.py", line 6, in <module>
    import Leap
ImportError: No module named Leap
```

The file /usr/bin/Playground_Data/Plugins/x86_64/libLeap.so exists,

and I can add /usr/bin to the PYTHONPATH but it still cannot find it.

I am using ubuntu 16.04.

Any ideas how I can make this find the library?

Kevin

Comment: Can you do `print(sys.path)` right before `import Leap`?

Comment: Where is your Leap.py?

Comment: This documentation describes a couple of ways to do it: https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/python/devguide/Project_Setup.html#importing-the-leap-motion-module

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but in Windows.

A change the Sample.py, adding the path to the Leap.py and LeapPython.pyd and it worked.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "../lib")
sys.path.insert(1, "../lib/x86")
```

Comment: this worked for me, but than i get ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_LeapPython)

Comment: ok this was my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55277328/unable-to-solve-importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-funct i was using python3 in place of python 2

Answer (score 0):

You need three files in the path: Leap.py, LeapPython, and libLeap (exact filenames and extensions vary by platform).

Leap.py loads LeapPython, which loads libLeap. If you are missing any of the three files you will get the same "no module" error message.