# Unable to solve "ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function"

Tags: python, python-3.x

The is [the link](https://drexel0-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/zc86_drexel_edu/Eb5NENK2nglLrK-jA-Qt_OwB9ns-xmUM_qj1iIpbdpBdPg?e=bwf73b) to the python package I am trying to compile and install. I have tried what I can find online for hours but cannot get over the `ImportError`.

The package has the following contents.

> [image]

Its setup.py has the following content. There are two modules here. One is the python wrapper package with `sparse_learning`, the other is a c extension module named `proj_module`.

> [image]

I followed the procedure described here https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/building.html to compile and install on Ubuntu 18.04. **There is no error message**.

> sudo python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
>   [image]
>
> sudo python3 setup.py install

Then when I try to load the C-extension module `proj_module`, an error "ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function" occurs.

> python3 -c "import proj_module"
>
> [image]

I tried to apply solutions found online, including uninstalling Python2 with `sudo apt purge python2.7-minimal`, or add python3 site-packages paths to the bashrc. However, none of them worked.
[image]

---

I just know it was originally written for Python 2. Then two modifications are made in the `main_wrapper.c` for it to run for Python 3. They look correct to me...

> Added:
>   [image]
>
> Changed:
>   [image]

Comment: Recommended to use text instead of image for code snippets.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you've got a little bit of Python 2-style code mixed in with your Python 3 module here. You just need to replace

`PyMODINIT_FUNC initproj_module() {`

with

`PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_proj_module() {`

in your `main_wrapper.c` file.

Comment: Probably a little late to ask this but I am going through this same issue, where can we find the documentation for python 3 vs python 2? there seem to be a lot of differences that are tough to find documentaion for.

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember where I found this! Might have been source-diving. I wish I could be more help.

Comment: I had a similar error, the answer was blaring in the eye, yet took me a while because the name of the module was `_modname` and I had to change to `PyInit__modname()` !!

Answer (score 10):

When using `pybind11` this error may suggest that the module name given in `PYBIND11_MODULE` doesn't match the filename of the library.

For example a library:

```
lib_abc.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

should be produced with the following module name:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(lib_abc, handle)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This error can also occur when you're using a build system like Cython and CMake. In `PyInit_<modname>`, `modname` should match the filename. For example, you might ask Cython to create the `extension` target, but CMake may produce `libextension.so` from that. When you then import `libextension` in Python, it will look for `PyInit_libextension` but Cython will have generated `PyInit_extension`.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this official document can be helpful; it works for me.

Just follow the steps shown in the picture:  [this pic shows how to address it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWS9j.png)

If you want to know more about it, please look up the official document, which can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31289912)